# How to wrap a native library with init/exit semantics

Tags: rust

I made a wrapper around a C library which creates a device that you must explicitly close.

Writing the raw FFI functions was easy, but how do I make it ergonomic Rust in a higher level wrapper?

Specifically, should I be doing it the RAII style and only using `Drop` to ensure the close is called when it goes out of scope, instead of exposing the `close()` method to the caller? Which way is the most idiomatic in Rust?

There are basically 3 options:

1. Thin wrapper that requires the same `close()` calls as the C library;
2. RAII style that has no exposed `close()`, only a `Drop` implementation;
3. C# `dispose()`-style implementation that tracks the closed state and allows both forms of closing.

The last form looks like this:

```
pub enum NativeDevice {} // Opaque pointer to C struct

fn ffi_open_native_device() -> *mut NativeDevice { unimplemented!() }
fn ffi_close_native_device(_: *mut NativeDevice) {}
fn ffi_foo(_: *mut NativeDevice, _: u32) -> u32 { unimplemented!() }

pub struct Device {
    native_device: *mut NativeDevice,
    closed: bool,
}

impl Device {
    pub fn new() -> Device {
        Device {
            native_device: ffi_open_native_device(),
            closed: false,
        }
    }

    pub fn foo(&self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
        ffi_foo(self.native_device, arg)
    }

    pub fn close(&mut self) {
        if !self.closed {
            ffi_close_native_device(self.native_device);
            self.closed = true;
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for Device {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Option number 2. I never saw option 1 or 3 used in rust. In your example, what happens when `close` is called more than one time?

Comment: Well spotted, the if-closed should of course go in the close() method and not in the drop(). Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idiomatically, I believe you would just implement `Drop`. I am unaware of any standard library types that implement the pattern of allowing the user to dispose a resource manually (calling a method) and automatically (by dropping).

This even leads to some strange cases. For example, closing a file via a function like `fclose` can generate errors. However, a Rust destructor can not return a failure code to the user. This means that [errors like that are swallowed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.8.0/src/libstd/sys/unix/fd.rs#L125-L134).

This leads to the reason that you *may* want to support both. Your `close` method could return a `Result` and then you could ignore that result in `Drop`.

---

As [Jsor points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172343/how-to-wrap-a-native-library-with-init-exit-semantics/37173021?noredirect=1#comment61949774_37173021), you'd probably want your `close` method to accept the type by value. I also realized you could use a `NULL` value to indicate if the value had been closed or not.

```
use std::ptr;

enum NativeDevice {} // Opaque pointer to C struct

fn ffi_open_native_device() -> *mut NativeDevice {
    0x1 as *mut NativeDevice
}

fn ffi_close_native_device(_: *mut NativeDevice) -> u8 {
    println!("Close was called");
    0
}

struct Device {
    native_device: *mut NativeDevice,
}

impl Device {
    fn new() -> Device {
        let dev = ffi_open_native_device();
        assert!(!dev.is_null());

        Device {
            native_device: dev,
        }
    }

    fn close(mut self) -> Result<(), &'static str> {
        if self.native_device.is_null() { return Ok(()) }

        let result = ffi_close_native_device(self.native_device);
        self.native_device = ptr::null_mut();
        // Important to indicate that the device has already been cleaned up        

        match result {
            0 => Ok(()),
            _ => Err("Something wen't boom"),
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for Device {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        if self.native_device.is_null() { return }
        let _ = ffi_close_native_device(self.native_device);
        // Ignoring failure to close here!
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _implicit = Device::new();
    let explicit = Device::new();

    explicit.close().expect("Couldn't close it");
}
```

---

If you had some kind of recoverable error that might occur when closing the device, you could return the object back to the user to try again:

```
enum Error {
    RecoverableError(Device),
    UnknownError,
}

fn close(mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
    if self.native_device.is_null() {
        return Ok(());
    }

    let result = ffi_close_native_device(self.native_device);

    match result {
        0 => {
            self.native_device = ptr::null_mut();
            // Important to indicate that the device has already been cleaned up
            Ok(())
        },
        1 => Err(Error::RecoverableError(self)),
        _ => {
            self.native_device = ptr::null_mut();
            // Important to indicate that the device has already been cleaned up
            Err(Error::UnknownError)
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: For the error reporting case, you could still have more Rustic sematics by having `fn close(self) -> Result` instead of `fn close(&mut self) -> Result`. Where the `Error` the result returns maybe contains `self`so you can do extra handling. The real issue here is use-after-resource-release.

Comment: closer to the latter.