# How do I wrap a native library with init and exit functions?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a wrapper for the [sane library](http://www.sane-project.org/), to access a scanner. This library has a sane_init and sane_exit function, which should be called respectively before and after using the library. How would I make sure that these are called exactly once? Expecting users of the wrapper to call init and exit functions doesn't seem to be very idiomatic Rust to me.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172343/how-to-wrap-a-native-library-with-init-exit-semantics), but that is about closing a device. Creating some kind of library object which closes the library in its drop-function wouldn't work. If we have multiple instances of the object, one instance might close the library while the other instance is still being used.

I've looked into creating a singleton to solve this, but could not find much about singletons in Rust, except that it is not advised to use them in Rust.

How would I solve this in Rust?

Comment: Same as in classic OOP languages, initialize in constuctor `YourWrapper::new()`, exit in destructor `impl<T> Drop for YourWrapper { fn drop(&mut self) {} }`

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48755465 Does this answer your question?

Comment: I'd just disallow creating multiple instances of the library object.

Comment: @SvenMarnach That still does not solve the problem of multiple instances of the library/context object

Comment: @JohnKugelman That almost sounds like a singleton. How would I make sure the constructor is only called once?

Comment: You could a global flag of some sort to prevent duplicates. The advantage over a singleton is that the user would control when initialization and de-initialization happen. Caveat: I'm only an intermediate Rust user so I don't know if this is the best way.

Comment: An alternative would be a global atomic counter counting the number of context objects that are out there. When your wrapper for `sane_init()` is called and the counter is zero, the actual `sane_init()` will be called before increasing the counter and handing out a `Context` object. The `Drop` implementation of `Context` decreases the counter, and if it's zero, `sane_exit()` is called.

Comment: Note that you don't need any mutex for these approaches – neither for the flag nor for the counter. `AtomicBool` or `AtomicUsize` will work fine.

Comment: @SvenMarnach A mutex is may be necessary to prevent a second init call from returning while the first one is still in flight.